# Laravel to Wordpress Migration

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, laravel

I'm looking to mirage a website which is running Laravel 5.2.x to the newest version of Wordpress.

I have created a theme to match the website the only issue I'm having now is trying to import over 1000 posts from the old database into Wordpress.

Does Wordpress have a tool or plugin to import a Laravel or Non-Wordpress database to Wordpress? My database only have a posts and category table which I would assume would be easy to bring over.

Comment: You should post the two schemas. And sample data would be nice too.

Comment: Laravel doesn't have a fixed database schema so there isn't going to be a nice neat migration tool. Your best bet is probably to write a script for it in your scripting language of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to script it out in PHP.  Fire up Laravel and load the Wordpress install as well.  Example how to: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files

Then iterate through the Laravel posts and map the fields to wordpress:

```
foreach(Posts::all() as $post){
  wp_insert_post([
    'post_title' => $post->title,
    'post_date' => $post->created_at->timestamp,
    // ...
  ]);
}
```

You could also use this library, which creates a database connection in Laravel that allows you to use eloquent to build WordPress posts: https://github.com/corcel/corcel

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I'll take a look and do something like this !